# How to see C++ function invocations behind the SWIG interface, TensorFlow

Tags: python, c++, gdb, tensorflow, swig

I'm working on TensorFlow and I want to know the relationship between each Python function and the correspondent C++ functions behind the SWIG  interface. 
In other words, I want to be able to know exactly which C++ functions are invoked for every line of Python code of my TensorFlow application.

I already saw how to debug the Python code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36399337/debugging-tensorflows-c-code-behind-the-swig-interface) and how to display at which line of code a segmentation fault happens [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2663841/python-tracing-a-segmentation-fault), but in these ways I'm able to see only where an error is, while instead I want to be able to know every C++ function invocation, even when there are no bugs in the code (At the moment debugging with gdb I'm able to see the system calls and the dynamic library calls, but not the C++ function invocations).

Comment: is this on Windows or Linux?

Comment: It's Ubuntu 14.04. The TensorFlow version instead is 0.10.0rc0.

Comment: Are there any better answers for this question?

Answer (score 3):

The bulk of the code that most people write is for graph construction. Almost of all of graph construction happens completely in Python, which simply builds up the (Python) data structures such as `Operation` and `Graph` defined in [`ops.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py). The one exception is shape inference, which happens when you create every operation. Shape inference calls out to C++ via the interface defined in [`cpp_shape_inference.i`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/framework/cpp_shape_inference.i). After you built up the computational graph, you *execute* it by creating a `Session` and calling `sess.run`. These are all Python function wrapping TensorFlow's C API. The wrappers can be found in [`tf_session.i`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/client/tf_session.i).

Comment: Hi keveman!I want to know which C++ functions are called in order to speed up the execution of some operations using a dedicated hardware accelerator. For example: if I see that the bottleneck of a TensorFlow application computation time is the training of a Neural Network (where a gradient optimizer is called several times in a loop),  at the moment I'm not able to know exactly which C++ functions are called behind Python functions (I can just guess about it, searching for them thoroughly the TF C++ API).
Debugging with gdb I'm able to see only the system calls and the dynamic library calls.