# Does TensorFlow gdb support breakpoint other than those in c_api.cc?

Tags: tensorflow, gdb

I tried following the instruction [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36399337/debugging-tensorflows-c-code-behind-the-swig-interface) (see also [here](https://gist.github.com/Mistobaan/738e76c3a5bb1f9bcc52e2809a23a7a1)) on how to use gdb with tensorflow. The ability to break at breakpoints seems really nice. However everybody quotes the same example of breaking at TF_NewSession (or TF_NewDeprecatedSession for later versions of tf). Are there examples of breaking at more internal functions such as ComputeAsync, RunAsync, etc? These methods are not exposed in the tensorflow/c directory but rather are part of internal classes like Ops or Iterators. Thanks.

John